# Unexpected start of array [

Tags: php, arrays

I keep getting this error

```
syntax error, unexpected '['
```

it is in the line 1 of the following code snippet:

Route.php

```
Route::get('api/test/{input}', [
    'before' => 'checkauth',
    "as"   => "test",
    "uses" => "TestController@show"
]);
```

what is wrong?

Comment: The array literal syntax `[1,2,3,4,5]` as opposed to the longer language construct `array(1,2,3,4,5)` require PHP 5.4+. You cannot use it on 5.3.3.

Comment: You need PHP/5.4 to use the [short array syntax](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). And you apparently [need PHP/5.3.7](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) to use Laravel. Your PHP is simply too old.

Answer (score 3):

Change your array notation.

```
Route::get('api/test/{input}', array(
    'before' => 'checkauth',
    "as"   => "test",
    "uses" => "TestController@show"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Berkowski says, the use of the array notation with `[` requires PHP 5.4+

From the [Php array documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

You should use the `array();` notation:

```
Route::get('api/test/{input}', array(
    'before' => 'checkauth',
    "as"   => "test",
    "uses" => "TestController@show"
));
```